# Delphi 2009 debugging breaks down unexpectedly?

Tags: debugging, delphi

I have one Windows 11 computer with Delphi 2009 whose debugging breaks down unexpectedly. This is problem with one computer only. The successful debugging process has event log entries:

```
Module Load: Windows.Storage.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $70730000. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
Module Load: Wldp.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $70590000. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
Thread Start: Thread ID: 17492. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
Module Load: CFGMGR32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $775F0000. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
Thread Start: Thread ID: 32. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
Module Load: CLBCatQ.DLL. No Debug Info. Base Address: $77A90000. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
Module Load: PROPSYS.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $703D0000. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
Module Load: profapi.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $704D0000. Process MyProject.exe (13860)
```

But the broken debugging process just spawns one Thread after loading CGMGR32.dll, then the whole Delphi hands for several dozens of seconds and then the Debug event log reports exiting this same thread and the following records are about exiting all the other (previously spawned) threads toos.

I enabled extended information on the Event Log and it shows many Windows events as well. But the Event log shows no Windows event after the last line which is about spawning of new thread, the immediate next messages are about closing this thread.

So - I don't understand what is happening? Whether the thread experiences some unrecoverable error during debug time the brokes down entire application and execution flow? Or maybe this thread can not load next two dlls (CLBCatQ.DLL, PROPSYS.dll)?

This problem is project and computer dependent. Simple (new VCL32 app with one button) debugs normally, one another large application exits already before the first code line of the project main file (dprj, there is no initialization section), one another smaller project starts normally but its debug brokes down at specific line (my collegue has not informed about this code yet) and so, the further debugging into this line can be possible...

I have found that Delphi debugger has very extensive logging capabilities https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Enabling_logging_for_the_RAD_Studio_debuggers and I am going to check them. But meanwhile - maybe there are some clues of suggestions already from the provided information how to repair the debugging that breaks down?

Comment: I believe [The Issue with Delphi Runtime Packages and Windows 10 Creators Update](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2017-june-delphi-packages-creators-update.html) blogpost from Marco Cantu might offer you more information about the issues you are facing.